# Outlook rules moving messages NOT from Inbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a rule for MS Outlook that would move selected messages from other folder than Inbox.

I'm receiving a lot of messages that I archive in a local PST file. However I want to avoid having my inbox full of correspondence until I turn on my laptop. So what I'd like to do is to set up a rule moving certain messages from my Inbox to a temporary folder (located on Exchange) and then, when I power up a desktop Outlook, have another rule checking if there's anything in the temporary folder, and if so, move it to the final folder.

Is such a construction achievable in Outlook?

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic, so the last part of your question asking for a *"third-party tool"* needs to be removed. As for the rest of the question, what have you researched and attempted so far? Because functionality is different, It would also be good to know what version of Outlook you are using.

Comment: I've removed the advice request. The application for which I'm seeking support is Outlook 2013 (though, I believe the potential solution would apply for older versions as well). I've searched the web, but obviously virtually every advice applies to creating very basic rules concerning messages incoming into inbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not achievable in Outlook out of the box. Its rules can only run *automatically* for *Inbox* messages. You can run rules for selected folders in *manual* mode only (using **Run Rules Now...** button above the list of rules).

The possible workaround is to run required rules against required folders using VBA macro by timer.

Comment: Thanks, fully understood! Looks like a third-party tool is necessary, as I already have too many VB scripts for other apps ;)